# Why is my styles not loaded in HEAD - Angular

Tags: css, angular

This makes my webpage to load without styles which stays for few seconds before the js loads the styles.

[image: Styles.js is loaded here and not in header]

I added my css in the angular.json file 

    `"styles": 
        [ 
            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", 
            "src/styles.sass" 
        ], 
    "scripts": 
        [ 
            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        ]`
 
is it not supposed to be there?

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Am I missing something, or are there no stylesheets visible in the screenshot.

Comment: @MrLister its in the `src="styles.js"`

Comment: @KENZiE That is not a stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Your styles are at the end of the document. nce all the assets in the document were loaded, the browser will load your styles. The browser renders your HTML code without any CSS because it doesn't have the styles yet.

Move the styles include to the `<head>`, this way, the styles will be loaded first.

Comment: I added my css in the angular.json file 
`           "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.sass"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
`
is it not supposed to be there?

Comment: `<script src="styles.js" />` should be placed at the begging of your HTML  , preferably inside the `<head>`

Comment: `<script src="styles.js" />` is auto generated by angular which places it below